# How do I mask objects using the depth buffer in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I'm writing a 2D game using three.js. First, I want to render background scenery. Then, I want to render a transparent quad (`opacity === 0`) that, even though you can't see it, it still writes values to the depth buffer. Then I want to render objects behind that have a z that places their fragments behind the transparent quad so that any fragments having the same screen space position as the transparent quad get discarded due to failing the depth test.

Based on my understanding of OpenGL, this is possible, but it seems three.js is not writing depth values for my transparent quad when the output of my transparent quad's fragment shader has `gl_FragColor.a === 0`.

I've set `renderer.sortObjects = false`. I have the background at `z = 0`, the transparent quad at `z = 1`, and the objects to be masked by the depth buffer at `z = 0.5`.

For the transparent quad I've set `material.transparent = false`, but instead of showing the background scenery over the transparent quad it shows the clear color.

Here is how I'm creating my transparent quad:

```
let uniforms = {
    color: {
        type: 'v4',
        value: new three.Vector4(0.2, 0.8, 0.8, 1),
    },
    opacity: {
        type: 'f',
        value: 1,
    },
    region_left: {
        type: 'f',
        value: -1,
    },
    region_right: {
        type: 'f',
        value: -1,
    },
    region_top: {
        type: 'f',
        value: -1,
    },
    region_bottom: {
        type: 'f',
        value: -1,
    },
}

let vertex_shader =
`varying vec2 screen_space_position;

void main()
{
    vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);

    screen_space_position = mvPosition.xy;

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
}`

let fragment_shader =
`uniform vec4 color;
uniform float opacity;
uniform float region_left;
uniform float region_right;
uniform float region_top;
uniform float region_bottom;

varying vec2 screen_space_position;

void main()
{
    // The following just checks a 2D box I've defined in 'screen space'
    // (really it's camera space, but I'm using an ortho camera where units
    // are pixels) and sets the opacity to zero if the fragment is inside
    // it.
    float final_opacity = opacity;
    vec2 position = screen_space_position;
    if (position.x >= region_left && position.x <= region_right &&
        position.y >= region_top && position.y <= region_bottom)
    {
        final_opacity = 0.0;
    }

    gl_FragColor = vec4(color.rgb, color.a * final_opacity);

    // I also tried just bypassing the above code and rendering 0 alpha
    // across the entire quad
    //gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 1, 1, 0);
}`

// Create geometry that represents a quad
let geometry = new three.PlaneGeometry(1, 1)

// PlaneGeometry assumes the lower left corner is (0, 0). This makes it
// so the upper left corner is (0, 0).
geometry.scale(1, -1, 1)

let material = new three.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms,
    vertexShader: vertex_shader,
    fragmentShader: fragment_shader,
    transparent: true,
})

let mesh = new three.Mesh(geometry, material)

// Center the mesh
mesh.position.set(0.5, 0.5, 0)

let root = new three.Object3D()
root.add(mesh)
```

Comment: Perhaps the three.js's default autoClearDepth = true is being triggered by the zero alpha? It is unclear from the docs what the test is for removing an object from the depth buffer. http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Renderers/WebGLRenderer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works as of `r73`. Careful control of your `three.Mesh` `renderOrder` and `position` properties is the solution.

First, I turned sorting back on by removing the `renderer.sortObjects = false` line. Second, I ensured the `z` position of the objects to be masked placed them behind the transparent quad.

Finally, I set `mesh.renderOrder = 1` (i.e. render this mesh after any other mesh with `renderOrder < 1`) for the `three.Mesh` objects for each of the scene objects I wanted to be masked and `mesh.renderOrder = 0.5` for the transparent quad. The default value for `renderOrder` is `0`, so any mesh's `renderOrder` I did not explicitly set renders as normal, before the transparent quad and the masked objects.

Note that `renderOrder` must be set per mesh. This property does not propagate to child `Object3D` objects.